# Nullable object must have a value While rendering a CheckBox in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create a CheckBox in MVC using Razor and here is the Below code for it :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PDModel.EducationMasterList[0].eduMarksheet, new { @class = "marksheet" })
```

But it is showing error **Cannot implicitly convert 'bool?' to 'bool'. Are you missing the type cast**. 
To Solve this i have used  `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PDModel.EducationMasterList[0].eduMarksheet.Value, new { @class = "marksheet" })` and it is giving this error : **Nullable object must have a value.**

and  `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PDModel.EducationMasterList[0].eduMarksheet.GetValueOrDefault(), new { @class = "marksheet" })` and it is giving this error : **Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.**

Any Suggestion will be thankful.

Thanks in Adavance

Comment: You should change your field to bool. There is no sense to have chechbox value which can be null.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a checkbox for a nullable bool. A check box has 2 states, `checked/true` and `unchecked/false`, but a nullable bool has 3 states, `true`, `false` and `null` so its not possible to post back a value indicating if its `false` or `null`.

You can use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PDModel.EducationMasterList[0].eduMarksheet, ...
```

which will render a dropdown list containing 3 values ("True", "False" and "Not set"). Another option is to create 3 radio buttons.

Note that `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PDModel.EducationMasterList[0].eduMarksheet.Value, ..)` would be pointless since it creates a checkbox and associated hidden input with the attribute `name="EducationMasterList[0].eduMarksheet.Value"` so when it posted back it would not match any model property and binding would fail.

Comment: Only if you make your property `bool`, not `bool?`

Comment: I can't make that feild bool? to bool because if user has not checked it , it should enter null value in that feild. Thats why i have made that feild Nullable

Comment: In that case you need `@Html.EditorFor()` or 3 radio buttons (for "true, "false" and "not set") as I indicated in my answer. But if the user has not checked it why cant that mean "false" instead of "null". A nullable bool is only required when you need 3 possible values for example - YES or NO or I DONT KNOW

Comment: Then change the property to `bool`. You cant do the impossible.

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider accepting the answer to close this out